# May one temporarily remove ẓiẓit from a garment in order to launder it?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan, washing-clothes

Maran HaShulḥan 'Arukh writes (Oraḥ Ḥayim 15:1) that is forbidden to remove ẓiẓit from a garment for no purpose (and the Mishnah Berurah there, s.q. 3, explains that this is to avoid disgracing the miẓwah).

However, the Mishnah Berurah seems to say (Oraḥ Ḥayim 21:3 s.q. 16) that, before giving one's tallit to a Gentile to launder, one should remove its ẓiẓit.

My question is: if I want to put my tallit (either gadol or qatan) in a laundry machine, am I allowed to remove its ẓiẓit beforehand since the whole purpose of removing them is to beautify the miẓwah (rather than disgrace the miẓwah)?

Answer (score 3):

In 21, 3 the Rama wrote:

> שלא ליתנו לכובסת גויה .‏
>
> Not to give Talit with tsitsit to a Gentile washwerwoman {Mishna Berura: instead, remove the Tsitsit before}.

In Gemara, there seems to be an additional problem (Menachot 43a) {note that the cases of Gemara are when a man wants to sell a Talit, which the Shulchan Aruch treats in 20, 2, not when he wants to give it to a gentile for washing as in the case above in Shulchan Aruch 21, 3}:

> And [this is so] not withstanding that they said, A man may not sell a garment furnished with zizith to a gentile unless he removed the zizith. What is the reason for this? - Here it was explained, on account of a harlot {*Rashi*:this Gentile will enter in relationship with a non-religious Jewish woman and they will marry}. Rab Judah said, It is to be feared that [an Israelite] might join him on the road and he might kill him {*Rashi*: he may use the Tsitsit to gain confidence of a Jew and kill him}.

Now consider SA OC 15, 1:

> מותר להתיר ציצית מטלית זה וליתנם בטלית אחר אבל שלא ליתנם בבגד אחר לא.‏
>
> It is permissible to remove tsitsit from this talit and fasten them to another talit; but to not fasten them to another talit, no.

The second part of the statement is an extract of **Tosfot Shabbat 22a** (Dibur Hamatchil Rav amar).

The reason is that now a mitsva will be cancelled from the Talit without a new mitsva for another Talit. The source is **Gemara** (Menachot 41b; **Shabbat 22a**): In Gemara, Rav said it's prohibited to move Tsitsit from garment to garment, and Shmuel allowed it. The Gemara for **Halacha follows Shmuel**'s opinion . Tosfot Shabbat 22a explained that Shmuel thinks that Tsitsit is "a duty of the garment, not of the man". Therefore, one is not allowed to remove them from a 4 Kanfot garment without other purpose. The problem is "mitsva's cancellation". So Magen Avraham explained that if the garment will be sold to a Gentile, anyway the garment of a Gentile has no duty of Tsitsit, so the vendor is allowed to remove the Tsitsit before. when giving the Talit to a whasherwoman (21, 3), the Talit remains duty, but the purpose is to fast a new tsitsit after laundry, so Mishna Berura allows. Mishna Berura on Siman 15, cited in the OP adds a reason (add a reason after the reason of cancellation of mitsva): disgracing Mitsva. (I guess that an example who need this reason is if a man fastens and removes tsitsit from a garment as a game, without purpose.)

Obviously, for your question, there is no cancellation of the mitsva and no disgracing if your intention is to fasten on this Talith a tsitsit (this tsitsit or new Tsitsit): maybe even according to Rav it is allowed. The SA OC in 21, 3 is perhaps not linked with your question. Magen Avraham 15, subparagraph 2 said in name of the Levush that one is allowed to remove tsitsit when his purpose is to fasten a more beautiful tsitsit.

Thus, to your question:

> if I want to put my tallit (either gadol or qatan) in a laundry machine, am I allowed to remove its ẓiẓit beforehand
> --> **Yes**.